# The action is undefined or invisible even if it seems written properly

Tags: javascript, function, redux, react-redux

I have to use useDispatch() for my toggle buttons so I have to refractor them from react to redux state. I was following the tutorial of basics of Redux and I think I have done that properly but when I try to at least useSelector to display the redux'state of button it doesnt show anything.

So here is my code:

// types.js in actions folder

```
   export const TOGGLE = "TOGGLE";
```

// buttonActions in actions folder

```
 export const toggle = () => {
return {
type: 'TOGGLE'
};
};
```

// buttonReducer in reducers folder

```
const buttonReducer = (state = true, action) => {
 switch(action.type) {
  case 'TOGGLE':
    return !state;
  default:
    return state;
};
};

 export default buttonReducer;
```

And the buttonReducer is imported into combineReducers which go to store.

The component code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import isloff from './mainpage_imgs/isloff.png'
import islon from './mainpage_imgs/islon.png'
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect, useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { toggle } from '../../actions/buttonActions'

  const Islbutton = props => {

const [open, setOpen] = useState(true);
const [role, setRole] = useState('');



useEffect(() => {
  if (props.auth.user) 
  { 
    setRole(props.auth.user.role);
  }
}, []);

const test = useSelector(state => state.button);

 const checkRole = (role) => {
  if (role === 'Menager' || role === 'Technolog')
   {
      return true }
    else 
    {
      return false
    };
}

const toggleImage = () => {
if(checkRole(role)) {
setOpen(!open)
};
}

     const getImageName = () => open ? 'islOnn' : 'islOfff'

const dispatch = useDispatch();

            return(

              <div>

                <img style={islplace} src={open ? islon : isloff }          
onClick={()=> dispatch(toggle())} />

              </div>
            );
    }


Islbutton.propTypes = {
button: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
auth: PropTypes.obj.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
button: state.button,
auth: state.auth
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {}), (Islbutton);
```

Comment: It is related to the main issue since the code doesnt work. Of course, I can show you the onClick = { () => useDispatch(toggle) } and the result of it which is 'toggle is not defined/ not a function' but its kinda worthless without showing the code which I did, right?

Comment: Okay, my bad then. Gonna edit it right now

Comment: Thank you for advices, I will follow them since it will help me improve but for now it works with dispatch(toggle()). I have a question for you because something unexcpected happened. It changes the state of all buttons now. In React it worked only for one, each one has its own button. Now its like no matter which one I click it will change the state for all of them. Is it any way to make one state for one button and go on? I have 16 the same buttons

Comment: Regarding `dispatch(toggle())` you're right (I got too much excited ;). Regarding your later issue, I don't quite see the entire picture of your app: would those buttons state depend on some other global state variable? do you even need to havethose buttons state stored globally? However, I've summarized my suggestions so far in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59684286/11299053). You're welcome to upvote/accept if it resolves your issues entirely ;) or proceed with further questions in the comment section under that one.

Comment: Sure, Im so thankful for your answers and suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your latest comments and my understanding of your use case I may suggest following distilled approach:

```js
//dependencies
const { render } = ReactDOM,
      { createStore } = Redux,
      { connect, Provider } = ReactRedux
      
//action creators
const SET_ROLE = 'SET_ROLE',
      MANAGER_APPROVED = 'MANAGER_APPROVED',
      setRole = role => ({type:SET_ROLE, role}),
      mngAppr = () => ({type:MANAGER_APPROVED})

//initial state, reducer, store
const initialState = {role:'Technolog', approved:false},
      appReducer = (state=initialState, action) => {
        switch(action.type){
          case SET_ROLE : {
            const {role} = state,
                  {role: newRole} = action
            return {...state, role: newRole}
          }
          case MANAGER_APPROVED : {
            const {approved} = state
            return {...state, approved: !approved}
          }
          default: return state
        }
      },
      store = createStore(appReducer)

//ui component to emulate toggling roles
const SwitchRoles = ({currentRole, switchRole}) => (
    <div>
      <label><input type="radio" name="role" value="Manager" onChange={e => switchRole(e.target.value)} />Manager</label>
      <label><input type="radio" name="role" value="Technolog"  onChange={e => switchRole(e.target.value)} />Technolog</label>
    </div>
)

//connect radio buttons click to togling roles action
const mapDispatch = dispatch => ({switchRole: role => dispatch(setRole(role))}),
      SwitchRolesContainer = connect(null,mapDispatch)(SwitchRoles)

//ui component to toggle 'approved' within global state      
const ToggleApprove = ({onApprove,isManager}) => (
  <button onClick={onApprove} disabled={!isManager}>Toggle</button>
)

//connect onToggle handler to dispatching 'toggle' action
const mapStateToProps = ({role}) => ({isManager: role == 'Manager'}),
      mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({onApprove: () => dispatch(mngAppr())}),
      ToggleApproveContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ToggleApprove)
      
//ui component to display current state of 'open'       
const IsApproved = ({isApproved}) => <div>{isApproved ? 'Approved by manager' : 'Not approved by manager'}</div>

//attach isOpen prop to global 'open' variable
const mapState = ({approved}) => ({isApproved: approved}),
      IsApprovedContainer = connect(mapState)(IsApproved)
      
//render the app
render (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <SwitchRolesContainer />
    <IsApprovedContainer />
    <ToggleApproveContainer />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.1.3/react-redux.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Hopefully, it gives a piece of mind about toggling global variables and mapping their values onto local components state.

Comment: Wow, I will test it in a second but I am afraid of adding role to it. The whole purpose of those buttons is to make them enabled only if user with specific role loggs in. So if user with Menager role logs in, he actually CAN click that button which changes state which changes picture. I just dont know how I could add the role requirements to that

Comment: And according to my issue from the top, it looks like that: 
https://gyazo.com/14a83fc2b687d71ee999027885dad6bb
All of the buttons 'get clicked' meanwhile only one truly gets. According to your words 'Do you need them stored globally' sadly, yes. I will have to push each one's state to localstorage to make them save even if the app is closed and I will have to use redux-persist for it as well

Comment: Gonna try it out! I will adjust it a bit since there is possibility of ' no logged in user' which is: ' role: ''  ' and ' role: korespondent ' but I think I will be able to do it due to your code you just created! Damn, if  thats gonna work as I think it will then you will be my God for real

Comment: May I ask is there any way to contact you in case?

Comment: I have checked your suggestion and it works phenomenal! I still struggle with the fact that if I click one button the rest of them get clicked as well. (All of the buttons are one component )

Comment: I did try to follow your answer but did not succeed too well :/

Comment: So here is a link for it : https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-frost-j8qde
The thing is I couldnt upload images which work as a toggle-button in my project because it was causing the crash for my browsers, I have no clue why.. 
I uploaded all of the needed files with the whole code, parts of code which are not neccessary just got commented by me. I hope its readable in some way..

Comment: @Goteii : Would you make your sandbox spinning to reproduce your issue, so I can see the actual behavior of your app and track down the issue you're facing? And, by the way, please, remove your previous comments - it's getting a bit messy over here ;)